# How to fix npm Error "timed out" after npm update

Tags: windows, npm, localhost, timeout

We have a React app, based on the Hydrogen theme for Shopify (which uses vite). It was all working ok until I had to add a package and update. It then started giving the following message: Error **timed out**. That is it, no other error message, I looked in the logs and there was nothing remarkable in there.

I tried removing the package, and all references to it in the code. But it looks like the issue may well have been the update command. But being rather new to React and npm on Windows, I have no idea how to fix it. Things that I did try were clearing the cache using:

npm cache clean --force

Doing another update. Removing the lock file.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to a method to debug that one-line error code, or could point me in the right direction? I am running on localhost, via Windows 10.

[npm error timed out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFDHU.png)

Answer (score 0):

My problem must have been a broken dependency. After a day or so of trying updates, it eventually just started working again. The update that actually worked had some vulnerabilities, so I ran an:

npm audit fix

After the npm audit fix, the code started running correctly again.